# Problem with bcrpyt hasher when logging in to user account

Tags: php, mysql, bcrypt

I created a registration and loging system!
There are no problems with registration.
I enter the desired username, the desired email, the desired password and hit enter,after hitting the enter, I come to the home page.
The problem is when I press the sign out button and when the leave button takes me to the login page,and when i re-enter username and password I get the "incorrect username or password" error.

```
   if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
        $repeatpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['repeatpassword']);
        $username_checker = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $email_checker = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $name_checker = mysqli_query($db,$username_checker) or die(mysqli_error($db));
        $mail_checker = mysqli_query($db,$email_checker) or die(mysqli_error($db));

        if(empty($username)){
            array_push($errors,"Username is required");
            return;
        }
        if(empty($email)){
            array_push($errors,"Email is required");
            return;
        }
        if(empty($password)){
            array_push($errors,"Password is required");
            return;
        }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($name_checker) > 0){
            array_push($errors,"Username is already recorded in our database");
            return;
        }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($mail_checker) > 0){
            array_push($errors,"Email Address is already recorded in our database");
            return;
        }
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)){
            array_push($errors,"The username is only derived from uppercase and lowercase characters");
            return;
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 5){
            array_push($errors,"Username must be at least 5 characters long");
            return;
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 8){
            array_push($errors,"Username must contain a minimum of 5 characters or a maximum of 12 characters");
            return;
        }
        else if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 12){
            array_push($errors,"Username must contain a minimum of 5 characters or a maximum of 12 characters");
            return;
        }
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            array_push($errors,"Invalid email format");
            return;
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 8){
            array_push($errors,"The password must contain a minimum of 8 or a maximum of 16 characters");
            return;
        }
        else if(strlen($_POST['password']) > 16){
            array_push($errors,"The password must contain a minimum of 8 or a maximum of 16
characters");
            return;
        }
        if($password != $repeatpassword){
            array_push($errors,"");
            return;
        }
        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
                    VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";  
            mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = " Welcome   ".$username."   ";
            $_SESSION['profile_name'] = $username;
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        if(empty($username)){
            array_push($errors,"Username is required");
            return;
        }
        if(empty($password)){
            array_push($errors,"Password is required");
            return;
        }
        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                if(password_verify($password)){
                 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                 $_SESSION['success'] = "  Welcome Back    ".$username;
                 $_SESSION['profile_name'] = $username;
                 header('location: index.php');
                }
            }
            else{
                array_push($errors,"incorrect username or password");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Looks like you store your password as hash and select with the plain text password

Comment: this query `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";` will always go straight to `else { ... 'incorrect username or password' }` because you're looking to match a user entered password to the hash in your database.

Comment: Once you've fixed that, `if(password_verify($password)){...` won't work. The function has the following signature: `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash ) : bool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you hash your password you create a new string (hash,) so it will never work if you try to match the hashed password with a password that's previously hashed.

Try this:

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password']))
    //True if password is correct
```

`$_POST['password']` is the password from the submitted form in plain text.

`$result['password']` is the hashed password in your DB.

And please look into PDO's prepared statements, your code is really dangerous like this.

Comment: again all the same

Comment: @Bushido95 Did you check if the data is in the database?

Comment: `$result['password']` wouldn't contain the hashed password, since `$result` is the returned value from `mysqli_query`. Need `mysqli_fetch_*` in between.

Comment: @Jeto How should I do that

Comment: @Bushido95 Learn about [prepared statements basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Jeto  I managed to fix I added mysqli_fetch_array to the while loop and did the above check in the while loop